# How do I do get the text from a failed `require` in Javascript?

Tags: solidity, javascript, error, ethers.js

I have a function in my smart contract that has several `require` clauses. I'm using `etheres.js` to call it from React. When it fails, all I get in the JS Error object is the message `"the execution failed due to an exception"` and `"Internal JSON-RPC error"`.

How can i get the text of the actual requirement that failed?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to get the specific error statement but this happens when the network rpc is not correctly entered or the account you are using has insufficient balance.